# How to find out data being buffered between two clients connected using unix domain socket on Linux

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I have a producer and a client connecting using Unix Domain Sockets. The netstat -nap command shows amount of data getting buffered between two processes for TCP/IP socket but not for Unix domain socket

How to find out send buffer and receiver buffer sizes for Unix Domain Socket from outside of the code?

Answer (score 0):

netstat does not have POSIX compliance.  That means you may not get identical information running netstat on different OSes.  tcp/ip buffer settings are normally a default system setting.

You have to login on both boxes to run netstat to get tcp internals information, for  the sockets. I'm sure you know that already, but I"m trying to be clear. tcp system information is in wildly different locations from Linux to another OS, say Solaris.

What is the output of `uname -a` on the UNIX box?

Comment: uname -a Linux 2.6.24-19-generic #1 SMP, but client and producer are on same machine using Unix Domain Socket (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). What I am looking for what is similar to netstat which shows data being buffered (SendQ and RecQ) for Unix Domain Socket.

Comment: /sbin/sysctl -p net.core.rmem_max and /sbin/sysctl -p net.core.wmem_max  give the current read and write buffer size settings.  You change this on a per socket basis with setsockopt(), or system wide with by editing /etc/sysctl.conf and using sysctl -s.   There is no netstat command to show the value on a per socket basis.  Plus netstat  program is obsolete. Replacement for plain netstat is ss. Replacement for netstat -r is ip route. Replacement for netstat -i is ip -s link. Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.